# how to retrieve data from database in struts 2

Tags: java, database, struts2

I want to display one of the data tables in my JSP page. My problem is that I have a form that is I have an action sending me to the JSP page I want to display my table in. I thought I would use another action to connect to the database and obtain all my information, but I'm not sure if that makes sense anymore, should I just use the same action?

Here are bits of my code:

Action to get the data:

```
import RegisterDao.*;

public class ProductAction {

    private String name,price,godown,product_type, description ;  
    private int product_id;


    public int getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(int product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGodown() {
        return godown;
    }

    public void setGodown(String godown) {
        this.godown = godown;
    }

    public String getProduct_type() {
        return product_type;
    }

    public void setProduct_type(String product_type) {
        this.product_type = product_type;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

JSP page:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Godown</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Product Type</th>
            <th>MRP</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="list">
        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="product_id"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="price"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="godown"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="product_type"></s:property></td>
            <td><s:property value="description"></s:property></td>
        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Struts.xml:

```
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="product"  class="Action.ProductAction">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: It's up to you, bu it seems you can't do either.